can I use this code to help improve playability of my game and how do I change it to make everything work as intended?
this code checks what key is pressed and uses that to change the outcome of the game(you know what I mean). I tried a couple of different ways of controlling this and nothing happened. I have attempted arrow keys and WASD to complete this task and nothing seems to work
here is my code

This is not related to any other question because it talks about different ways of doing something in something more specific than moving an object it is moving the object then checking where the object is in space and moving it via cloning in the next space over while deleting the original.

I don't know how to reply to comments so if you want and know how just send me a personal comment if that is even possible on this platform and I will send you the full 156 lines of code that I have to make this easier to solve. I also wish that this platform would let me post this with more specifics but it says "This problem has already been solved" and it is nothing like the code I have

import pygame
from random import shuffle, randint

pygame.init()

cell_size = 20
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (245, 245, 245)
red = (255, 0, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)

green = (0, 255, 0)

passage_list = []

potential_passage_list = []

impossible_passage = []

random_cell = []

done = False

player_pos = []


info_object = pygame.display.Info()

screen_width = info_object.current_w

screen_height = info_object.current_h


maze_length = screen_width - 1

maze_height = screen_height - 1

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((maze_length, maze_height), pygame.RESIZABLE)

pygame.display.flip()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def one_connection(cell_x, cell_y):
    count = 0
    if [cell_x + cell_size, cell_y] in passage_list:
        count += 1
    if [cell_x - cell_size, cell_y] in passage_list:
        count += 1
    if [cell_x, cell_y + cell_size] in passage_list:
        count += 1
    if [cell_x, cell_y - cell_size] in passage_list:
        count += 1
    if count <= 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def valid_cell(cell_x, cell_y):
    if [cell_x, cell_y] in potential_passage_list:
        impossible_passage.append([cell_x, cell_y])
    elif [cell_x, cell_y] in impossible_passage:
        impossible_passage.append([cell_x, cell_y])
    elif cell_x < 0 or cell_x >= maze_length - cell_size or cell_y < 0 or cell_y >= maze_height - cell_size:
        impossible_passage.append([cell_x, cell_y])
    elif not one_connection(cell_x, cell_y):
        impossible_passage.append([cell_x, cell_y])
    elif (([cell_x + cell_size, cell_y + cell_size] in passage_list and [cell_x + cell_size, cell_y] not in passage_list and [cell_x, cell_y + cell_size] not in passage_list) or
          ([cell_x + cell_size, cell_y - cell_size] in passage_list and [cell_x + cell_size, cell_y] not in passage_list and [cell_x, cell_y - cell_size] not in passage_list) or
          ([cell_x - cell_size, cell_y + cell_size] in passage_list and [cell_x - cell_size, cell_y] not in passage_list and [cell_x, cell_y + cell_size] not in passage_list) or
          ([cell_x - cell_size, cell_y - cell_size] in passage_list and [cell_x - cell_size, cell_y] not in passage_list and [cell_x, cell_y - cell_size] not in passage_list)):
        impossible_passage.append([cell_x, cell_y])
    elif [cell_x, cell_y] not in passage_list:
        return True

def maze_passage(cell_x, cell_y):
    block_passage_list = []
    potential_passage_list.remove([cell_x, cell_y])
    if valid_cell(cell_x, cell_y):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, [cell_x, cell_y, cell_size, cell_size])
        pygame.display.update()
        passage_list.append([cell_x, cell_y])
        if valid_cell(cell_x + cell_size, cell_y):
            block_passage_list.append([cell_x + cell_size, cell_y])
        if valid_cell(cell_x - cell_size, cell_y):
            block_passage_list.append([cell_x - cell_size, cell_y])
        if valid_cell(cell_x, cell_y + cell_size):
            block_passage_list.append([cell_x, cell_y + cell_size])
        if valid_cell(cell_x, cell_y - cell_size):
            block_passage_list.append([cell_x, cell_y - cell_size])
        shuffle(block_passage_list)
        for j in block_passage_list:
            potential_passage_list.append(j)

start_cell = [randint(0, int(maze_height / cell_size))*cell_size, randint(0, int(maze_height / cell_size))*cell_size]
potential_passage_list.append([start_cell[0], start_cell[1]])

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
            screen = pygame.display.set_mode((event.w, event.h), pygame.RESIZABLE)
            maze_length = event.w - 1
            maze_height = event.h - 1
            screen.fill(black)
            for cell in passage_list:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, [cell[0], cell[1], cell_size, cell_size])
            pygame.display.update()

    for i in range(1, len(potential_passage_list) + 1):
        if randint(0, int(len(passage_list) / 50)) == 0:
            maze_passage(potential_passage_list[-i][0], potential_passage_list[-i][1])
            break

    clock.tick(10000)

    if not potential_passage_list:
        run = True
        while run:
            clock.tick(10000)
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    run = False
            passage_list.sort()
            player_pos = passage_list[0]
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, [passage_list[0][0] + 1, passage_list[0][1] + 1, cell_size - 2, cell_size - 2])
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, blue, [passage_list[-1][0] + 1, passage_list[-1][1] + 1, cell_size - 2, cell_size - 2])
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, green, [player_pos[0] + 1, player_pos[1] + 1, cell_size - 2, cell_size - 2])
            pygame.display.update()

        while run:
            clock.tick(10000)
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    run = False
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    new_pos = player_pos.copy()
                    if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                        new_pos[0] -= cell_size
                    if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                        new_pos[0] += cell_size
                    if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                        new_pos[1] -= cell_size
                    if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                        new_pos[1] += cell_size

                    # Check if the new position is within the maze boundaries and is a passage
                    if new_pos in passage_list:
                        player_pos = new_pos

            if player_pos == passage_list[-1]:
                print("You win!")
                run = False
            screen.fill(black)
            for cell in passage_list:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, [cell[0], cell[1], cell_size, cell_size])
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, green, [player_pos[0] + 1, player_pos[1] + 1, cell_size - 2, cell_size - 2])
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, [passage_list[0][0] + 1, passage_list[0][1] + 1, cell_size - 2, cell_size - 2])
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, blue, [passage_list[-1][0] + 1, passage_list[-1][1] + 1, cell_size - 2, cell_size - 2])
            pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()

